# Getting value from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My project `ClaimTrax.Web` has a folder `'App_GlobalResources'` which has resource file `'DisplayMessages.resx'` in which I have Name as `'UserLockMessage'` and value as

> 'Your account has been locked. Please contact Admin.'....

My namespace and class and method wherein I want string message from `'DisplayMessages.resx'` is below:-

```
namespace ClaimTrax.Business.Laserfiche
{
    public sealed class LFAPIInterface
    {
       public string CheckLoginAttempts(User user, string message) 
       {
```

What namespace if needed should I add and how to get the message from reource file `'DisplayMessages.resx'` which is in folder `'App_GlobalResources'` in same project?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: `ClaimTrax.Business.Laserfiche.Properties.Resources.UserLockMessage` store it as `string`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
string usrmsg = ClaimTrax.Business.Laserfiche.Properties.Resources.UserLockMessage;
```